# A bug in the new top bar where inbox and recent reputation icons become unclickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

**Description:** The inbox icon and reputation icon does not open the respective boxes anymore.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click on the inbox icon
2. Click on the reputation icon
3. Click on the stackexchange icon

Now clicking on the inbox or reputation icon again won't open them until you refresh the page.

Windows 8.1, IE 11, Chrome 31

Comment: Confirmed for Chrome & Windows **7**

Comment: Hmm, curious. Same on Firefox (Win7)

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 25 on Windows 8.

Comment: This won't work for the reputation icon too. To be precise if you click both before clicking the StackExchange icon both will not open. If you only click the inbox button, the reputation icon will open as expected.

Comment: Repro Chromium on Linux

Comment: A more general procedure to reproduce: if you open the inbox panel or the reputation panel before having opened the SE panel, that respective panel will no longer open.

Comment: That's a very peculiar bug... :)

Comment: Dr.House of web pages.

Comment: Reproed on Chrome Infinity and OS X.

Comment: I'm amazed nobody blamed caching just yet.

Comment: I guess when click the exchange icon the other boxes are hidden using CSS `display: none;` but then tries to open using `jQuery.Show()` or something similar...

Comment: Also on FF 17, Win 7.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 31 on Mac OSX 10.8.5. Actually once the problem starts occurring, clicking on the icon sets `display:none` on the `topbar-dialog` element instead of setting it to `display:block`. Looks like its hiding it instead of showing it. Test it by removing the inline `display:none` style on the element.

Comment: We're aware of this, and we're working on it.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell [meta-tag:status-planned] then?

Comment: Now it is solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to update this, but a large JS refactor fixed the issue a while ago.